# HTTP GET request cross-origin error for FRED API

Tags: javascript, api, get

I am simply trying to get data from the FRED API using a get request. I keep getting "No Access-Control-Allow-Origin header is present on the requested resource. Origin null is there not allowed access'. I reviewed all of the API documentation and there is no reference to anything additional required for the get request. Is there a specific line-item I can add to my existing code to satisfy this 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header requirement? Could you give an example of what those line(s) would look like? I included my code with working API key. thank you

```
  <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script>

function httpGet(theUrl)
{
    var xmlHttp = null;

    xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.open( "GET", "http://api.stlouisfed.org/fred/releases/dates?api_key=1cee0e87e5e3362716028352d3d1c160", false );
    xmlHttp.send( null );
    return xmlHttp.responseText;
}
</script>



</head>

<body>
<button onclick="httpGet()">http GET</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You function `httpGet` using cross-domain request if you domain is not `stlouisfed.org`. So if API response don't have `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` header all requests will fails.
As I understand `FRED API` is using only by desktop programs, not web apps.

But there is a `iframe transport` to circumvent this. I create html [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/frontenddeveloping/8j8g7/) where you can press the button and see API result in `iframe`. But I have a problem with iframe `onload` event in this jsshell site - it always broken. You can add `iframe.onload` in your code to get the answer from API, then the form will change the iframe.

Answer (score 1):

> I reviewed all of the API documentation and there is no reference to anything additional required for the get request.

Their documentation is not specific to JavaScript running in a browser.

> Is there a specific line-item I can add to my existing code to satisfy this 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header requirement?

No. You need to make the request from your server.

> Could you give an example of what those line(s) would look like? I included my code with working API key.

Your API key should be kept secret (which is any other reason to not do this directly with client side JavaScript).